# Flask handling vue 3 views

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, server-side-rendering

I’m working on a project using Flask for the backend and Vue.js for the frontend. I want Flask to determine which view to render based on the selected route. Has anyone successfully implemented this with Vue.js 3?

I came across a tutorial that used a Vue config file to copy the vue/index.html to the index.html in Flask’s templates folder. However, this approach seems tailored for Vue 2, and I’m facing difficulties adapting it for Vue 3. Any insights or guidance on achieving this integration in Vue 3 would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.